# Labeling line features using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, road

I used the following code to label the line features(roads) in a layer.It works in the console, but not by python code(application) It works for the points too.

What did I do wrong?

```
 def labell(self):
    layer = self.iface.mapCanvas().currentLayer()
    palyrr = QgsPalLayerSettings()
    palyrr.readFromLayer(layer)
    palyrr.enabled = True
    palyrr.fieldName = 'name'
    palyrr.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'08','')
    palyrr.writeToLayer(layer)
    layer.commitChanges()
    self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()
```

Comment: Please could you provide more info? Do you are getting some error? What you mean "but not by python code"?, Are you trying it as an external standalone script?

Comment: I'm developing a plugin so I tried this in my code. It doesn't give an error. For line features-it enables all the settings but does not apply them to the layer. When I go and check layer properties->Label tab, it shows that the "Label this layer with name" is checked but I have to still press "OK" to apply them to the layer. I even added the codings "layer.commitChanges()" and "self.iface.mapCanvas().refresh()". But they didn't apply. But this code works perfectly and apply the labelling, when I copy and run in qgis console. What Should I do to apply changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what could be the difference between console and plugin,  I think it should to work either way. Also you try to replace `layer.commitChanges()` (which makes not sense there) with `layer.triggerRepaint()` and look if that helps (note it is not necessary to call `mapCanvas.refresh()`). You can also use custom properties for the layer to enable labeling, a sample code is the following:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "name" )
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.Line)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize","8" )
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled","true" )
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

**EDIT**

for linear features you have to set the placement property as well. I changed the above code.
Your first posted code should also work by adding the following line:

```
palyrr.placement = QgsPalLayerSettings.Line
```

You can use other placement attributes please have a look at this [link](http://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html#a5d449d8e9cb89e5d453c6e33fe1c66cc)

Comment: I tried your code, but same as before. It works for points, but not for line features.

Comment: please check out if it works with the changes above.

Comment: @Dil Hi, I can't seem to get it to work. Just like Dil I manage to change the properties but still have to hit OK. I am using Irssvt's script. In addition: I am trying to add a buffer around my label but can't seem to get it to work. I tried by adding this to the script: layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/DataDefinedProperties",QgsPalLayerSettings.BufferDraw)