# How to batch label features using PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, labeling, batch

I am writing a python script to label features (lines). However I can't figure out:

1. how to get the script to turn on the buffer
2. how to get the script to apply the changes. When I currently run it, it changes everything in the properties (except the buffer) but I still have to hit ok before QGIS applies it to the map.

.

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "Length" )
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/predefinedPointPosition", QgsPalLayerSettings.BottomRight)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize","10" )
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/buffer",QgsPalLayerSettings.BufferDraw)
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled","true" )
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

I have had a look at one similar question but I cannot seem to figure it out:
[How to label line features using python code?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122280/how-to-label-line-features-using-python-code)

Once I get this to work I want to transform it into a batch-script by adding some lines like:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
```

Comment: I only knew I could upvote but didn't see the little "accept" button. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To turn on the buffer, you can use:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferDraw", True)
```

You can also set various properties as described in the [QgsPalLayerSettings class](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsPalLayerSettings.html) such as the size:

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferSize", "5")
```

---

So if you would like to apply this to all your loaded layers, you could use something like:

```
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "Length" )
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", QgsPalLayerSettings.Horizontal)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/predefinedPointPosition", QgsPalLayerSettings.BottomRight)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize","10" )
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/bufferDraw", True)
    layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled","true" )
    layer.triggerRepaint()
```